# SOQL query with Date fields is not returning the expected result

Tags: apex, soql

```
Event e = new Event();
e.ActivityDate = Date.newInstance(2005,05,25);
insert e; //inserting an event record with all the required fields.

//The below 4 lines are just to check if am doing it as expected.
Date d1 = Date.newInstance(2005,05,05); //Same date in query.
Date d2 = Date.newInstance(2005,06,05); //Same date in query.
Boolean b1 = e.ActivityDate > d1; //This is true
Boolean b2 = e.ActivityDate < d2; //This is true

List<Event> myList = [SELECT id, ActivityDate FROM Event WHERE ActivityDate > 2005-05-05 AND ActivityDate < 2005-06-05];
System.assertEquals(1,myList.size()); //System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 1, Actual: 0
```

The main goal is to filter a few records based on the dates but it won't return any records. The `ActivityDate < 2005-06-05` is working fine in the query but not the first part.

```
//good
List<Event> myList = [SELECT id, ActivityDate FROM Event WHERE ActivityDate < 2005-06-05];
System.assertEquals(1,myList.size()); //true

//bad
List<Event> myList = [SELECT id, ActivityDate FROM Event WHERE ActivityDate > 2005-05-05];
System.assertEquals(1,myList.size()); //System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 1, Actual: 0
```

I should be missing something very silly. Please advice, thank you.

Comment: Silly question but are you use ActivityDate is a field of type Date and not DateTime?

Comment: Did you expect this to be greater than or equal to? `WHERE ActivityDate > 2005-05-05`

Comment: @Apz I am not sure what exact data you are using but following worked for me in my Sandbox.  

Event e = new Event();
e.ActivityDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(2005,05,25,12,00,00);
e.ActivityDate = Date.newInstance(2005,05,25);
e.DurationInMinutes = 30;
insert e;


List<Event> myList = [SELECT id, ActivityDate FROM Event WHERE ActivityDate > 2005-05-05 AND ActivityDate < 2005-06-05];
System.assertEquals(1,myList.size());

Comment: It is expected to return the list size 0 as ActivityDate is not greater than 2005-05-05 . You have to use DateTime if you want it to work as your  expected

Comment: @CharisMoutafidis ActivityDate is a field of type Date. If this was the case then it'd throw a compile error.

Comment: @MarkPond Greater than. I also tried with equal to but no difference.

Comment: @NoorAShuvo Correct me if am wrong, May 25th, 2005 is greater than May 5th, 2005.

Comment: So what was the issue?

Comment: Had to give the same value for ActivityDateTime along with ActivityDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Apz I am not sure what exact data you are using but following worked for me in my Sandbox.

```
Event e = new Event();
e.ActivityDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(2005,05,25,12,00,00);
e.ActivityDate = Date.newInstance(2005,05,25);
e.DurationInMinutes = 30;
insert e;


List<Event> myList = [SELECT id, ActivityDate FROM Event WHERE ActivityDate > 2005-05-05 AND ActivityDate < 2005-06-05];
System.assertEquals(1,myList.size());
```

Comment: Great catch, now it returns that event. Although StartDateTime and EndDateTime fields were required on my org. So does this say that ActivityDateTime should be filled, in order to give an ActivityDate?! Also, in my code snippet, both the boolean flags were true but the SOQL query was still returning nothing. Just curious what's happening.

Comment: @Apz Dealing with Activities / Events / Tasks can be tricky sometimes. I would suggest try and provide as much information possible as yours had limited in the question. Nonetheless, this community is very active and helpful. All the best.